# List of All Folders and Sub-folders

Tags: linux, ls

In Linux, I want to find out all Folder/Sub-folder name and redirect to text file

I tried  `ls -alR > list.txt`, but it gives all files+folders

Comment: Use the `find` command. `find . -type d`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use `find`

```
find . -type d > output.txt
```

or `tree`

```
tree -d > output.txt
```

`tree`, If not installed on your system.

If you are using `ubuntu`

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

If you are using `mac os`.

```
brew install tree
```

Comment: In this Option , is there an Option to exclude one single folder... I have a ~snapshot folder in it, which I want to exclude?

Comment: find . -type d -name ~snapshot -prune > output.txt

Comment: It is great ! And how can we order it by alphapetic order ?

Comment: @sangorys you can use sort like this  `find . -type d |sort > output.txt`

Comment: This solution doesn't list softlink subdirectories

Comment: `brew` is not standard on MacOS; you have to install that separately.

Answer (score 10):

```
find . -type d > list.txt
```

Will list all directories and subdirectories under the current path. If you want to list all of the directories under a path other than the current one, change the `.` to that other path.

If you want to exclude certain directories, you can filter them out with a negative condition:

```
find . -type d ! -name "~snapshot" > list.txt
```

Comment: My preference is "du|less" (or "du | cut -f 2|less") ... but your solution is better :)

Comment: In this Option , is there an Option to exclude one single folder... I have a ~snapshot folder in it, which I want to exclude?

Comment: @Sandeep540 Sure. `find . -type d ! -name "~snapshot" > list.txt`

Answer (score 3):

As well as `find` listed in other answers, better shells allow both recurvsive globs and filtering of glob matches, so in `zsh` for example...

```
ls -lad **/*(/)
```

...lists all directories while keeping all the "-l" details that you want, which you'd otherwise need to recreate using something like...

```
find . -type d -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

(not quite as easy as the other answers suggest)

The benefit of find is that it's more independent of the shell - more portable, even for `system()` calls from within a C/C++ program etc..

Comment: In this Option , is there an Option to exclude one single folder... I have a ~snapshot folder in it, which I want to exclude?

Comment: @Sandeep50: in zsh, yes: `setopt EXTENDED_GLOB`, then `ls -lad **/*~**/~snapshot(/)`. Details: from `man zshall` / "x~y (Requires EXTENDED_GLOB to be set.) Match anything that matches the pattern x but does not match y. [...]".  (There's also "^x (Requires EXTENDED_GLOB to be set.) Matches anything except the pattern x. [further explanation of slightly different syntax + example]")