# How to get the number of files with a specfic extension in a directory and it's sub directories on Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

The question is itself self-explanatory.

I tried the following command I found somewhere on the internet but it shows the number just in the immediate directory and not its subdirectories.

```
ls -lR ./*.jpg | wc -l
```

I am searching for all the files with the extension ".jpg" in the current folder and its subdirectories.

Comment: I would suggest using find, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827686/list-of-all-folders-and-sub-folders#14827721) answer for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' | wc -l
```

Find all the files (type f) that have a name that matches '*.jpg' then count them with wc

Answer (score 1):

It's a job for `find`:

```
find -name "*.jpg" | wc -l
```